# Multiple(Same) Restful service call using Apache Camel instead of Java Futures

Tags: java, spring, apache, rest, apache-camel

I have a requirement. We have a CSV file which contains multiple rows.Each Row represents drug information. When i upload the file, i need to take each row and then call a RestFul Service call.
currently i am refactoring a for loop using a java.util.concurrent.Executor Service, so that i can make calls parallely.
I am thinking of camel.

can someone throw some light on how to use camel in such scenarios.

**Current Loop**

```
for(Drug cdrug:drugGroup.getDrugs())
{   
  for(Drug d:drugs)
  {
        if(cdrug.getDrugId().equals(d.getDrugId()))
        {
             httpClient.callRestFulService(d);
        }
  }
}
```

Regards
Ram

Comment: Have a look at the following components: The [file2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) endpoint will provide a stream from the file for you. The [splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) will read the stream and trigger parallel processing of the lines. The [http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) endpoint allows you to call a REST service.

Answer (score 0):

Ralf gives you the right headwords.

The Question about [processing large csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122748/best-strategy-for-processing-large-csv-files-in-apache-camel) will give you an example, with the reading and processing part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. got solved after using the separators. thanks for the help.