# Processing large compressed files in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to get a single file with **.zip** compression from a ftp server and trying to store it in S3 with **.gzip** compression using camel.
Following is the route I currently have.

```
from("sftp://username@host/file_path/?password=<password>&noop=true&streamDownload=true")
    .routeId("route_id")
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
    .unmarshal().zipFile()
    .marshal().gzip()
    .to("aws-s3://s3_bucket_name?amazonS3Client=#client");
```

This works fine for smaller files. But I have files that are ~700 MB in size when compressed. For files of that size I get `OutOfMemoryError for Java heap space`

I know there is a streaming option in camel (`.split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()`) but I am not sure if I can umarshal and marshal while streaming. (I see a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122748/best-strategy-for-processing-large-csv-files-in-apache-camel) but in this case the source file is plain text / csv).

The second part to the problem is streaming the file back to S3. I am aware of the **multiPartUpload** option in **[camel-aws](http://camel.apache.org/aws-s3.html)** component but it seems to require the source to be a file. I do not know how to achieve that.

Can this be achieved without processing (unzipping and then gzipping) the file using java code in a custom processor ?

Environment: Camel **2.19.3**, Java 8

Thanks

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I too have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `streamCaching()`. So the way I would do that is

```
from('xyz')
.streamCaching()
.unmarshall().gzip()
.to('abc')
.end()
```