# Read large amount of data from CSV and XML file Using Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to read large amount of data **CSV and XML** files(approximately more than **1GB** each file) using **Apache Camel**?

If any performance issues or limitations involved in this case, what kind of solutions are available from Apache Camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer about csv is here 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122748/best-strategy-for-processing-large-csv-files-in-apache-camel)

For consuming large xml file you can use 
http://camel.apache.org/stax.html

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing the issue,I found a following Solution.

So 1 GB is not soooo much,if we can simply spend enough RAM on the Camel.

It depends on the following question

Do we need the 1 GB at the same time to access or Do we access all the files in any order?

If not, then we would have to "stream" the CSV / XML file, so read as InputStream and then sequentially get what we need.

**CSV:**

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <split streaming="true">
        <tokenize token="\n"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </split>
     <unmarshal><csv /></unmarshal>
</route>
```

**XML:**

```
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>    
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <split streaming="true">     
       <ref>staxRecord</ref>     
      <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </split>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```