# Split and tokenize a large file with regex using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to read a very large flat file of around 1 GB using Camel. The records are separated by a set of strings, and I am trying the below route.

```
from(incomingFilePath+"?delete=true")
                .split()
                .tokenize("ENDRECORD")
                .streaming()
                .bean(bean, "method")
                .bean(bean,"method")
                .end();
```

The streaming works in the above case. But when I try to tokenize using a regex, my streaming fails and I am getting an Out of Memory Exception.

```
from(incomingFilePath+"?delete=true")
                .split()
                .tokenize("\\|END(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)", true)
                .streaming()
                .bean(bean, "method")
                .bean(bean,"method")
                .end();
```

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Some references:

- [Best strategy for processing large CSV files in Apache Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122748/best-strategy-for-processing-large-csv-files-in-apache-camel)
- [Apache Camel out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419529/apache-camel-out-of-memory-exception)

Comment: Showing the value of `RECORD_SEPARATOR_REGEX` might be helpful...

Comment: @JimGarrison added. Will that matter?

Comment: Did you try the regex manually on a small snippet? Do you really want to split by "|END" followed by any kind of newline? (CRLF, CR or LF) Just asking cause of the first `|`, but may be totally legit.

Comment: @Halley Yes, if it's particularly complex.

Comment: @cyberbrain doesn't matter. The moment I use a regex, the streaming stops working.